# How to whitelist range of MACs in 75-persistent-net-generator.rules?

Tags: debian, virtualization, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, udev

I have a Debian Squeeze (2.6.32-5) guest in KVM that has all virtio network interfaces, and their MACs are apparently blacklisted by udev as per /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules such that /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules is not generated.

I tried making a /etc/udev/rules.d/010_netinterfaces.rules file to define eth(foo) per MAC(foo), but it was ignored.

So now I'm unable to explicitly define interface names.

Can someone advise as to how the /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules needs to be edited whitelist these MACs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently /etc/udev/rules.d/010_netinterfaces.rules is ignored in Squeeze.

I ended up editing /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.

Then renamed /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules to /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules.disabled so /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules would stay put.

Comment: If you create an empty /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules if will "override" the one in /lib/... so there's less chance of it returning after a patch/upgrade.  (I think it needs at least one line in it or a single comment - "touch" creates one that is too empty and causes an error)